# Xcode not showing output

Tags: c

I was instructed to write a game of dice in C language in which the computer and the user act as competing sides of the game. First, a random number is generated by the computer, and then the string "g" command input by the user is accepted to generate the user's random number (simulate to roll a dice once), and compare their values. If the random number obtained by the user is less than that obtained by the computer, output "Sorry, you loss!", if the results is otherwise, output "Congratulations, you won!".

The code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
 srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
 int com_inp = (rand() % (6 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
 int user_inp=0;
 char ch;
 scanf("%c",&ch);
 if(ch=='g')
 user_inp = (rand() % (6 - 1 + 1)) + 1;

  if(user_inp<com_inp)
     printf("\n Sorry, you lost!");
  else
     printf("\n Congratulations, you won!");

     printf("\n Computer dice = %d \t User dice = %d",com_inp,user_inp);

  return 0;
}
```

After running on Xcode v12.2, no output is shown. The console is blank.

However, the output is shown if the program is run on Dev-C++(Windows).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Terminate your printing messages with a newline — it's optional to put a newline at the start, but you get more reliable output if you finish messages with a newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything printed before the `scanf`. I am not familiar with Dev-C++ on Windows, but in the Xcode console there is no prompt to show you that it is waiting for input, so you might want to put something like:

```c
printf("Enter a number between 1 and 6\n>");
```

before your `scanf`.

You may also be running into some line-buffering issues. Try adding `\n` at then end of each line you are printing.

```c
  if(user_inp<com_inp)
     printf("\n Sorry, you lost!\n");
  else
     printf("\n Congratulations, you won!\n");

     printf("\n Computer dice = %d \t User dice = %d\n",com_inp,user_inp);
```

Comment: The console is still unable to generate any output.

Comment: If you run  a simple C "hello world" program are you seeing output then?

Comment: And if you add a prompt, like I suggested, does the prompt appear?